# linq check a string value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Is there a better way to write the below using Linq.

need to check if the value return by  a bool is true and false

```
string checkvalue = nodeIterator.Current.Value.ToString();
if (checkvalue == "true")
{
    taxSpecification = 3;
}
else if (checkvalue == "false")
{
    taxSpecification = 3;
}
```

Comment: Is it always bool? I mean the only acceptable values are "true" and "false"

Comment: Is taxSpecification really going to always be 3? Your code reads fine, but you could use the ternary/conditional (?:) operator, for example if you wanted to reduce the lines of code. Are you sure nodeIterator.Current.Value will always be non-null? Linq would be more helpful if we could see the structure you are iterating over.

Comment: Actually, it's typical, isn't it. No matter what happens, tax is constant ;-)

Comment: LINQ is not magic pixie dust that you should sprinkle over all code. Concentrate on getting the logic right.

Comment: @dash - unless you're Jimmy Carr (for our UK readers).

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string to return a bool:

```
bool myBool;
if (!bool.TryParse(checkvalue, out myBool)
    throw new Exception("This is not a valid bool");
...
```

If you want a more general approach (i.e. the string might not be a valid TryParse value):

```
if(new[] {"true", "false"}.Contains(checkvalue))
    taxSpecification = 3;
```

This doesn't really address the Linq part but could help in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        var checkvalue = "false";
        bool myRes = false;
        int tax = 0;

        if (bool.TryParse(checkvalue, out myRes))
        {
            tax = (myRes) ? 3 : 4;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Linq, but you can write it as

```
if (checkvalue == "true" || checkvalue == "false")
{
    taxSpecification = 3;
}else
{
  // wrong input 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use LINQ or some fancy thing when a simple .Net 2.0 logic would suffice

```
switch (nodeIterator.Current.Value.ToString())
{
    case "true":
    case "false":
         taxSpecification = 3;
    break;
}
```